# I'm writing a subtitle reading app. I want it to run similar to how a player would however I'm struggleing with timing

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, milliseconds, subtitle

Below is code that should display a subtitle at the exact millisecond that it should appear on screen.

```
public void ticktime(){
        // Start long running operation in a background thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < endtime) {
                    progressStatus += 1;
                    // Update the progress bar and display the
                    //current value in the text view
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mProgressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                            SubTitle st = Subtitlelist.get(NextSubtitle);
                            if (Integer.valueOf(st.SRTStart0.replaceFirst("[.].*","")) <= progressStatus){
                                mcontextReader.setText(st.SRText);
                                CurrentSubtitle = CurrentSubtitle+1;
                                NextSubtitle = CurrentSubtitle+1;
                                Log.d("NextSubStart1: ",st.SRTStart0.replaceFirst("[.].*",""));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

It seams no mater how i change the sleep the timing will get out of sync at some point. Maybe sleeping the thread is not a good way to do this.

Comment: "Maybe sleeping the thread is not a good way to do this." I agree. The expected time will rapidly diverge from the actual time. What you need is a clock. Try [`uptimeMillis()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis()). You can still `sleep()`, just use the clock to help you decide _how long_ to sleep.

Comment: will try over this weekend. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: i ended up using elapsedRealtime() since the description stated it keeps time even when screen is off.